# DataTemplateSelector throwing MS.Internal.NativeParseException

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have a dynamic pivot item template as listed below:

```
<controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:DropPageSelector Content="{Binding}">
                                    <local:DropPageSelector.hasImage>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <!--Code-->
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </local:DropPageSelector.hasImage>
                                    <local:DropPageSelector.noImage>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <!--Code-->
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </local:DropPageSelector.noImage>
                                </local:DropPageSelector>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot>
```

And here is my code to DropPageSelector datatemplate selector class:

```
class DropPageSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate noImage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public DataTemplate hasImage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            News nws = item as News;
            if (nws != null) 
            { 
                if ( nws.Image != null || nws.Image =="" )
                {
                    return hasImage;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return noImage;
                }
            }
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to run the code I'm getting these following errors:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.NativeParseException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.dll
Additional information: Unspecified error
```

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pivotitem throwing MS.Internal.WrappedException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696693/pivotitem-throwing-ms-internal-wrappedexception)

Comment: I didn't get any answer on that and this is a whole new scenario.

Comment: I've got the same issue. No solution in sight.

Comment: Same here. Also no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this one. 
Problem was that the class

```
class DropPageSelector : DataTemplateSelector
```

is not public. It should be

```
public class DropPageSelector : DataTemplateSelector
```